# Missing parameter but need parameter to be changed based on user input

Tags: ios, swiftui, parameters

This file is for the main structure of the application.  This is where the error is coming from which is "Missing argument for parameter 'numberOfDoors' in call". This is because it wants me to add

```
ContentView(numberOfDoors: <#Int#>)
```

but im having trouble finding out how I can get what the user chooses to be the int instead of me putting a number in there statically.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct NumOfDoorsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
 }
```

This is my project file.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var numberOfDoors: Int
@State var multiOptions: Array<String>

init(numberOfDoors: Int) {
    self.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors
    self.multiOptions = [String](repeating: "", count: numberOfDoors)
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form{
            Section {
                Picker("Number of doors", selection: $numberOfDoors) {
                    ForEach(1 ..< 64) {
                        Text("\($0) doors")
                    }
                }
                
                ForEach(multiOptions.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    TextField("Enter your option...", text: $multiOptions[index])
                        .padding()
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                Text("\(numberOfDoors + 1)")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important parts of SwiftUI programming is creating an appropriate model for your views.

`@State` properties are OK for local, often independent properties, but they typically aren't a good solution for your main data model or where a model needs to be manipulated by the user.

In your case you want the size of the array to change based on the selected number of doors, so you need somewhere for that procedural code to live; The model is that place.

Here is a simple model object you can use

```
class DoorModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var numberOfDoors: Int {
        didSet {
            self.adjustArray(newSize: numberOfDoors)
        }
    }
    @Published var doors:[String]
    
    init(numberOfDoors: Int) {
        self.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors
        self.doors = [String](repeating: "", count: numberOfDoors)
    }
    
    private func adjustArray(newSize: Int) {
        let delta = newSize - doors.count
        
        print("new size = \(newSize) Delta = \(delta)")
        
        if delta > 0 {
            doors.append(contentsOf:[String](repeating: "", count: delta))
        } else if delta < 0 {
            doors.removeLast(-delta)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you still need to supply a starting number of doors via the initialiser for your model.  Whenever that value changes, the `didSet` property observer calls a function to add or remove elements from the end of the array.

You can use this model in your view with an `@StateObject` decorator.  This ensures that a single instance is created and reused as your view is redrawn

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model = DoorModel(numberOfDoors: 1)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form{
                Section {
                    Picker("Number of doors", selection: $model.numberOfDoors) {
                        ForEach(1 ..< 64) { index in
                            Text("\(index) doors").tag(index)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ForEach($model.doors.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        TextField("Enter your option...", text: $model.doors[index])
                            .padding()
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added the `.tag` modifier to ensure that the picker works correctly with your 1-based list; By default the tag will be 0 based.

Comment: @Pailw11 By chance do you know how I can implement a reset button with the code laid out the way you did above? I've been trying to get a function set up or really anything to reset it back to the starting screen of the app.  Keep getting the error that my index is out of range.

Comment: What do you want the reset function to do?  You can add a function to the model that sets `numberOfDoors = 1` and sets `doors[0]=""`

Comment: That is what I have tried to do reseting those but then when I hit the reset button it always says "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range". Do you know why that happens? @Paulw11

Comment: You have to be careful since setting `numberOfDoors` will trigger the `didSet` and modify the size of the array. [Here](https://gist.github.com/paulw11/f7c1201ad2651c88fd8f229ad56c85f4) is my modified view and model that includes the `reset()` function.  It works for me

Comment: I'm still getting that index out of range error when I click on the reset button.  I'll try to dig more into it and see if I can understand it. I greatly appreciate all your help.

Comment: With my code?  What sequence of operations are you doing?  Can you upload your code as a gist?

Comment: Sorry I ended up playing around with it more.  Your code was perfect and it does work for me now also.  The problem I believe is the words very trying to spell check and I didn't hit return so it through an error when I tried to reset it.  But now if I hit return then it does reset it back to its normal state. Thank you so much you have been so helpful, been trying to figure out resetting for a while now.

Comment: Its just if I don't press return and have the keyboard showing that it breaks the code, but as long as I do press return then everything is good.

Comment: The problem is that there is a conflict between field that the keyboard is currently associated with and the row being removed from the list.  I updated the gist to put in some workaround code to fix this.  To be honest this UI isn't typically how you would structure this kind of thing.  You would have a + button somewhere to add another row and support deleting individual rows by swiping on them.

Comment: I'll have to look into swiping to delete the rows because that would be a nicer implementation and then deleting would be easy to get the specific row that you want.  I've been trying to learn how to create good UI but still have a ways to go.

Answer (score 0):

There are, to my opinion, two issues with your code.

1. Don't initialize ContentView with a parameter. Especially, since you want to start with a value of 0 doors and let the user choose how many doors.
2. You can't initialize an @State value directly like: self.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors.

I suggest the following code, it worked for me.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var numberOfDoors: Int
    @State private var multiOptions: Array<String>

    init() {
        _numberOfDoors = State(wrappedValue: 0)
        _multiOptions = State(wrappedValue: [String](repeating: "", count: 1))
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form{
                Section {
                    Picker("Number of doors", selection: $numberOfDoors) {
                        ForEach(1 ..< 64) {
                            Text("\($0) doors")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(multiOptions.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        TextField("Enter your option...", text: $multiOptions[index])
                            .padding()
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    }
                }
                
                Section {
                    Text("\(numberOfDoors + 1)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is, that when you initialize ContentView, the @State or @StateObject variables don't yet exist. You first need to initialize the View, before you can assign an @State variable.

An @State variable is wrapped in a property wrapper, where the original variable at initialization is _variable. Therefore, you need to initialize an @State variable like this:

```
_myVariable = State(wrappedValue: myContent)
```

If you don't so it is like this, you get the error as you mentioned.

Comment: Before I had initialized it I had my variables like this, `State var numberOfDoors: Int = 0`
    `State var multiOptions: Array<String> = [String](repeating: "", count: numberOfDoors)`, But I have been getting this error if you could help me with it, "Cannot use instance member 'numberOfDoors' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" @MacUserT

Comment: That is a different problem. You can't initialize number of doors like you do in an initializer. I will update the answer.